# E-Mail duplicates when GMail filters and Thunderbird runs

Tags: thunderbird, email-client, gmail-imap

The question is related to [Outlook + IMAP + Gmail: Remove duplicated e-mails](https://superuser.com/questions/488589/outlook-imap-gmail-remove-duplicated-e-mails)

GMail filters incoming e-mail and apply labels to it, which means that the mails are sorted in the respective folders.

There is one big problem I noticed recently. While the local email client (Thunderbird) is running, every email for which filters apply gets duplicated: One mail remains in the inbox while the other is in the (accurate) folder. The first duplicate disappears once I sort it into the folder manually.

There is no problem when the Thunderbird is not running. The solution to the other question is quite unappealing: Stop syncing certain folders. I thought, 2.5 years later there might be a solution to this problem, even if it's one that only works with Thunderbird.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I forward email from one gmail account to the other, then use thunderbird to auto move the email to a folder. If done so, I get 2 emails. Never was able solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I draw the wrong conclusion from the duplicate behaviour: It's not so clear that the Thunderbird/Gmail filters combo is causing the problem. It may have been an issue of Gmail filters alone.

I realized, that duplicates are created even when Thunderbird is not running. I then checked the box `Skip the inbox (Archive it)` and it solved the problem:

[image]